# Plotting terrain data with matplotlib plot_surface

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot terrain elevation data with matplotlib.  I build up a nx3 numpy array, with each row containing the x, y, z coordinates of my points (they're regularly spaced in a grid on the x, y plane).  I am attempting to plot it with this code:

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

print desiredData[:,0]

surf = ax.plot_surface(desiredData[:,0], desiredData[:,1],
                       desiredData[:,2], rstride =1,
                       cstride = 1, cmap=cm.jet,
                       linewidth = 0, antialiased = False)

plt.show()
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "gisConvert.py", line 203, in <module>
linewidth = 0, antialiased = False)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 663,
in plot_surface
rows, cols = Z.shape
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error suggests,

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

You are using a 1D-array but `plot_surface` expects 2D arrays for `X`, `Y` and `Z`.

And that is why you get the `ValueError`.

Comment: Quite right. OP, check out the examples/mplot3d directory for some good examples of how to use plot_surface.

Comment: So instead of the nx3 array I should have 3 mxp arrays?  I assume that's so matplotlib can identify the structure of the data?

Comment: @Ben Jones:  You need 2D arrays for the co-ordinates, yes.